# Why not to use closures for object attributes?

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

I'm currently writing objects in javascript and I would like to do it in a clear, nice way, using best practices etc. But I'm bothered that I must always write `this.` to address attributes, unlike in other OO languages.

So I got the idea -  **why not just use closures for object attributes?** Look at my example object. So instead of this, classical way:

```
var MyObjConstructor = function (a, b) {

    // constructor - initialization of object attributes
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.var1 = 0;
    this.var2 = "hello";
    this.var3 = [1, 2, 3];

    // methods
    this.method1 = function () {
        return this.var3[this.var1] + this.var2; 
            // terrible - I must always write "this." ...
    };

}
```

... I would do it **using closure** and then I don't need to write `this.` every time to access the attributes!

```
var MyObjConstructor = function (a, b) {

    // constructor - initialization of object attributes
    // the attributes are in the closure!!!
    var a = a;
    var b = b;
    var var1 = 0;
    var var2 = "hello";
    var var3 = [1, 2, 3];

    // methods
    this.method1 = function () {
        return var3[var1] + var2;
            // nice and short
    };

    // I can also have "get" and "set" methods:
    this.getVar1 = function () { return var1; }
    this.setVar1 = function (value) { var1 = value; }
}
```

Also, it has a hidden benefit that the attributes really cannot be accessed any other way than by get/set methods!!

#### So the question is:

1. Is this a good idea? Is it "clean", is it conforming to best practice?
2. Are there any other semantical differences between these 2 solutions?
3. Are there any traps with using closure like this?

Comment: maybe object copying wouldn't work?

Comment: That are two different things - use `this.prop` to define a public property, use `var prop` to define a private property. You cannot use one instead of the other, they serve different purposes.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas `var prop` defines a local variables that can only be accessed inside the constructor or inside functions defined in the constructor. The term `private` is misleading.

Comment: To lessen the confusion: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions directly:

**1. Is it OK to use objects as closures? Is it conforming to best practices?**

Yes. In some situations you really want to have private fields so this is <s>the only way</s> one the ways to do that. For a real, concrete, example have a look at Deferreds/Promises in Dojo or JQuery. The Promises implement just the non-mutating subset of deferreds so they need to keep their inner Deferred private to avoid others from changing it directly.

Do remember that you should only  really use hidden fields where you really need them (and not for trivial reasons like not having to type "this"). Using plain old public fields and "normal" objects is also perfectly fine, especially if you consider that they have some advantages that the closure version doesn't have:

**2. Is there any semantic difference between these two versions?**

Yes.

- You can't inspect private fields directly (duh). This also means you can't easily clone objects or do other kinds of reflection on them.
- Accessing a field via an object property instead of a direct reference allows you to use prototypal inheritance. The parts that matter are that:

  - You have a hard time overriding things in a subclass (variables in a closure are static, not virtual)
  - You can't add other methods latter that use these hidden fields (since they are only accessible inside the constructor function). Particularly nasty for subclassing.

**3. Are there any traps on using a closure like this?**

Most Javascript engines today are less performant on code with lots of closures compared to code that uses prototypes. Not a "real" reason for a difference (since LISP engines have been fine with closures since forever) but something you will have to live with.

Comment: You can implement Deferreds/Promises without closures. Closures vs prototypes is really just a style thing or "do what you feel like".

Comment: Well, not if you really want the promises to hide their private state. Otherwise you just get the Deferred part.

Comment: you would end up having to use `.bind` and some kind of proxy pattern.

Comment: True... I'm still on a mindset of having to support older stuff where a closure is the only way to do a `bind`. :) (Although I'm sure it wouldn't be that hard to find more examples out there of things that are more idiomatic to do with closures)

Comment: Thank you for response, nice analysis.

Answer (score 9):

95% performance decrease.

An actual [Benchmark](http://jsperf.com/proto-vs-closure-25235) so for your (simple) example were talking 50%-85% performance decrease across browsers.

Seriously, closures are slow as hell.

Now using closures for data isn't the problem, but using closures for functions/methods is. And you can't do one without the other. Methods that live on the prototype have no mechnanism of accessing *local* variables that live inside the constructor.

And the other problem is your "classical" example doesn't use the prototype :\

What you really want is

- [Doing OO properly](http://raynos.org/blog/5/Doing-Object-Oriented-Javascript---part-2)
- [Understanding prototypes as classes](http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/prototypes-as-classes.html)

So the following is also bad.

```
var MyObjConstructor = function (a, b) {

    // constructor - initialization of object attributes
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.var1 = 0;
    this.var2 = "hello";
    this.var3 = [1, 2, 3];

    // methods
    this.method1 = function () {
        return this.var3[this.var1] + this.var2; 
    };

}
```

You want

```
// constructor - initialization of object attributes
var MyObjConstructor = function (a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

Object.extend(MyObjConstructor.prototype, {
    var1: 0,
    var2: "hello",
    var3: [1, 2, 3],
    // methods
    method1: function () {
        return this.var3[this.var1] + this.var2; 
    }
});
```

For some value of [Object.extend](https://github.com/Raynos/pd#pd.extend). Here were placing any common data or methods on the prototype and *sharing* that data among *all* instances. This way we are not memcopying everything everytime everywhere.

> // terrible - I must always write "this." ...

The alternative is duplicating state for every single object. The closure pattern is nice and all but it's just not performant.

Comment: thanks for the links, however I don't like to use new library (`pd`) - is there some similar instruction how to do OO, but with just "bare" hands? (or, maybe using jquery).

Comment: @TomasT. sure there is. Do it the verbose way. `pd` just makes it less verbose. Or do it the "classical" way.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't the jQuery framework use closures almost entirely? Why would they use closures for the entire library if it was such a performance issue?

Comment: I'm fiddling around with your library, but I must be doing something wrong. Your code seems to extend the constructor, not the prototype of it. http://jsfiddle.net/mK4ws/ An instance does not have `var1` available.

Comment: @MrMisterMan because jQuery is slow as hell. I mean, meh jQuery is not optimised at the javascript level, it's optimised at the DOM level.

Comment: @pimvdb sorry I was supposed to extend `MyObjConstructor.prototype` >_<

Comment: Why are you using v2 of the jsperf case rather than v1? The "do it 100 times" just obscures useful data. It will take a little less than 100 times as long. If you were trying to show what it's like when you do it lots, whether it speeds up after time, jsperf does that for you already.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I don't trust jsperf. There is a difference between creating just one instance (n times) and creating n instances (m times).

Comment: @Raynos: sure there is, but it's not much and the extra confusion that doing it your way adds is in my opinion strongly undesirable.

Comment: @Raynos, you say one of the main reasons not to use closure is performance. But I use it for object which will never be copied, will be created once at the beginning and that's all. Do you then have any argument against the closure solution, as I sketched it?

Comment: @TomasT. no but that object which is only created once should be an object literal.

Comment: I think saying closures are slow doesn't mean they are bad. The important question with performance is where is most of the processing done. Jquery is hugely powerful but you wouldn't use it an animation loop.

Comment: @SteveO'Connor there are defiantly use-cases for closures. The above isn't one of them and jQuery abuses closures.